# Controller is not receiving data send from Ajax

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, asp.net-core

I am sending ajax post to a controller with a list of data, but the controller is receiving null

I tried changing the ajax or the controller, but nothing helped.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult AddToCart(List<ProductInsert> data)
{
     var userId = _userManager.GetUserId(User);

     foreach (var p in data)
     {

            if (userId == null)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException($"Unable to load user with ID '{userId}'.");
            }
            else
            {
                _repository.InsertToMyCart(p.Product_Id, userId, p.Id);
            }
     }
     return RedirectToAction("Home", "Products");
}
```

Here is my scripts:

```
var Id = 0;

function buyProduct(Product_Id) {
    Id++;
    var data = { Product_Id: Product_Id , Id: Id };

    $.ajax({
      url: '/MyCart/AddToCart',
      type: 'POST',
      data: JSON.stringify(data),
      dataType: 'json',
      contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
      success: function (result) {
          console.log(id);
      }
    });
}
```

namespace ASP.NET_core_role_based_authentication.Controllers

```
{
    public class ProductInsert
  {
      public string Product_Id { get; set; }
      public int Id { get; set; }
  }
```

}

Comment: send data as array  like this ' var data =  [{Product_Id: Product_Id , Id: Id}] ; '

Comment: Thank you, but it's stil not working like this.

Comment: @Nadia what is your 'ProductInsert' class , kindly include details in your question

Comment: If your controller doesn't have the `[ApiController]` attribute, you'll need to also add `[FromBody]` like this: `[FromBody] List<ProductInsert> data`.

Comment: @Nadia Where is your `ProductInsert` model class? add this to the question please! It clearly look like your passing data and controller method parameter are not in same shape.

Comment: Even if I add [FromBody] it's not working              
I added the class to the question

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this , this is the correct way

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "load-vorlage",
            data: {Product_Id: Product_Id, Id: Id},
            beforeSend: function () {
                // loader
            },
            error: function (response) {
                console.log(request.responseText);
            },
            success: function (data) {
                // success
            }
        });
```

So if this does not work, you should check if variables have values.

other ways

```
data:"{'Product_Id':'"+Product_Id+"','Id':'"+Id+"'}"
```

or as string with &, should be proper

```
var data = 'Product_Id='+ Product_Id  + '&Id='+ Id;
```

Comment: Thank you, there are values in Product_Id and in Id, but they are not mapped to the controller and I tryied this ways and it's still not working

Answer (score 0):

Although you haven't posted your actual controller class, I'm reasonably sure that it is not decorated with the `[ApiController]` attribute:

```
[ApiController]
public class MyAwesomeController : ControllerBase
```

It looks as though you're using a standard MVC-style controller, which while there's no *real* difference between that and an API controller, it is now typical to both inherit from `ControllerBase` (rather than `Controller`) and add the `[ApiController]` attribute to controllers that will function like an API, rather than returning views. That leads to a number of differences, chief among which to your issue here being how post data is bound.

The default binding source for a class param is `[FromForm]`, i.e. a `x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` encoded request body - *not* `application/json`. To accept something like `application/json`, `application/xml`, etc. The param must have the `[FromBody]` attribute applied to it:

```
public IActionResult AddToCart([FromBody]List<ProductInsert> data)
```

When your controller has the `[ApiController]` attribute, this logic is reversed. `[FromBody]` becomes the default, and you must apply `[FromForm]` if you need to accept a standard HTML form post.

Long and short, the immediate fix is to add `[FromBody]` to your param, since you're attempting to send JSON.

However, you also have some other issues here that will rear their ugly heads once you solve your immediate issue. Namely, you're using AJAX to hit a standard MVC-style action which does a redirect. AJAX requests are made via a thin client, which means that nothing happens automatically with the response, per se. An AJAX request can be made to automatically follow a redirect, but the result of that is that you're simply going to end up with the entire page you're being redirected to returned into your AJAX success callback. At that point, there's nothing really to do. You can't change the entirely document's HTML via JS. If you don't auto-follow the redirect, you can get the URL to follow from the `Location` header of the response, and then set `location` to that in JS. However, that negates the entire purpose of using AJAX in the first place: you might as well just do a standard form post, as the result will be exactly the same, just without a bunch of useless JS required.

If you want to use AJAX, then the endpoint you hit should return something you can actually work with: a JSON object or a partial HTML fragment. If you opt to return JSON, then you'll need to utilize that returned data to do something useful on the page, like letting the user know in some way that the product was successfully added to the cart. If you return a partial, then you would select some element in the DOM and replace its HTML with that partial HTML document. Long and short, no matter what is returned to your AJAX success callback, *you* must do something with it - nothing happens automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .Net Core, most likely you have to use [FromBody] in the API method declaration:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult AddToCart([FromBody] List<ProductInsert> data)
```